# Node openpgp error when encrypting: Could not find valid key packet for encryption in key

Tags: node.js, encryption, key, pgp, openpgp.js

I have a error when trying to encrypt a string with a pgp public key:
'Could not find valid key packet for encryption in key 9ae788ff8eec0b31'

This error doesn't appear with every key but with most of them. Here one of the keys that errors:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.43

mI0EXQJU0gEEAKZKsTmlR71mPgzQR6hyGJXR4tuoH/RgJPnZGCKPlJqCj8GCvlTa
Jqy5gUZQJItwS4ssFU56+fI1a47oe08covHWgLAsGRWCxsD/oneFhddPhhZkHOui
s1CW3CNDQ8hhl/DykhUoegKCmvNDzRVsD4y7ueLkzAisu3MH3ShQWDB/ABEBAAG0
CUxJTlhPIFNBU4icBBABAgAGBQJdAlTSAAoJEPa8OTh7Vcnz4kID/0KL7RBA5Z83
WuirfaVXF+Kqi4QXQO4EBUUknSbO+igRSJ/MLV4NROuhn2AZ3YWXK9B8rLsaZy9Q
49/rr1lPn648Wq2lAoN7uLwtycspFQscjLT76hDMnoOvJGzjrpi+xC7n0W7ggLRN
TkCUB8b+OBvwPhptny8kS6DASwew0Fp7
=2Sis
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Here is the function im using to encrypt

```
    const openpgp = require('openpgp')
    async function pgpEncrypt(pubkey, message) {
        await openpgp.initWorker({ path: 'openpgp.worker.js' })
        const options = {
            message: await openpgp.message.fromText(message), // input as Message object
            publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for encryption
            armor: false
        }
        const cipherText = await openpgp.encrypt(options)
        return cipherText.data
    }
```

What's wrong with this? how can i ensure the key works with this library?

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a version issue. Try the 4.10.8 version of openpgp. Use the following lines for the dependencies.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "openpgp": "^4.10.8"
}
```